How to combine multiple audio blobs, buffers or urls into one?
I have multiple audio urls, I tried converting these audio into blobs and combining them in a deno server but weirdly the final blob only plays the first audio. What did I do wrong here?
Code with audio urls:
const audioPromise = audioUrls.map((url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.arrayBuffer()));
const buffers = await Promise.all(audioPromise);
const combinedBuffer = combineAudioBuffers(buffers);
const combinedBlob = new Blob([combinedBuffer], { type: "audio/wav" });
return combinedBlob;

Code for combining array buffers
function combineAudioBuffers(buffers: ArrayBuffer[]): ArrayBuffer {
  const totalLength = buffers.reduce((sum, buffer) => sum + buffer.byteLength, 0);
  const result = new Uint8Array(totalLength);
  let offset = 0;
  for (const buffer of buffers) {
    result.set(new Uint8Array(buffer), offset);
    offset += buffer.byteLength;
  }
  return result;
}

